# AWS DynamoDb Session Handler in PHP: session_id() returns different values between EC2 instances

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I have 2 EC2 instances with Apache2 and PHP.

Both instances contains the session handler of AWS DynamoDB and the values were written in database. But when I try to get session_id(), returns two differents values...

What is wrong?

Comment: Sorry @klode, I'm trying to get the PHP session and manipulates it through the AWS DynamoDB. But the sessions ids are in 2 different servers instantiated. I wonder how can I be more clear? I do not speak English very well, so excuse me for the spelling mistakes.

Comment: My mistake, your question was clear enough in fact you got an answer. I will delete my comment. ;)

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know the session_id isn't shared between instances. It is simply an easier way to call dynamodb from php code. Every EC2 will have a different session to DynamoDB.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.DynamoDb.Session.SessionHandler.html

Answer (score 0):

I understood the problem ...

I was trying to do tests on my local machine and on an EC2 instance, when I put the code below in 2 EC2 instances functioned normally.

```
use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Session;

try {
    $dynamoDb = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
        'key'    => 'AWS_KEY',
        'secret' => 'AWS_SECRET',
        'region' => 'AWS_REGION'
    ));

    $sessionHandler = $dynamoDb->registerSessionHandler(array(
        'table_name'               => 'session',
        'hash_key'                 => 'id',
        'session_lifetime'         => 3600,
        'consistent_read'          => true,
        'locking_strategy'         => null,
        'automatic_gc'             => 0,
        'gc_batch_size'            => 50,
        'max_lock_wait_time'       => 15,
        'min_lock_retry_microtime' => 5000,
        'max_lock_retry_microtime' => 50000,
    ));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```