# Sharing session between EC2s with DynamoDB

Tags: php, session, amazon-dynamodb

I'm currently working on setting up DynamDB to store my PHP sessions. The reason I want to do this is I want to do a blue-green-ish deployment from one server to another, i.e. setup a second EC2 instance with newer software than the current server, then switch the EIP from the old one to the new one.

My problem is, of course, PHP sessions are stored locally on the old EC2 and I don't want to lose any sessions in the switchover or have any downtime. I thought if I stored the sessions on DynamoDB that would take care of of the sessions when I switched over. But then I read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791908/aws-dynamodb-session-handler-in-php-session-id-returns-different-values-betwe) which implies I can't do that.

So, can I or not? If not, what is the best way to switch servers without losing PHP sessions?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found was using Zebra Sessions: https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Session

It really is a drop-in replacement.